# How to pass a list of class object into a multiprocessing.process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocess

I have a box of atoms, around 200k, and I want to calculate the distance of between atoms. It took a really long time without using a parallel method to do this calculation. So I want to use pool.map to help me with this. I first sliced the box into several small cells and defined a cell object which contains all atoms information within that cell. However, when I failed to pass the list of cell object to the process. I am a beginner of this multiprocessing task, can anyone has some idea how to fix this? Here is a simplified of my script:

```py
class atoms():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__idx__ = 0 # Has other function to change this idx and coord
        self.__coord__ = [x, y, z] 
    def getIdx(self):
        return self.__idx__

class cell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__idx__ = 0
        self.__atoms__ = [atom1, ...,]
    def outInfo(self):
        for a in self.__atoms__:
            print(a.getIdx())

from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(cell_lists):
    for c in cell_lists:
        print(c.outInfo())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cell_lists = [cell1, cell2, ..., cell8]
    p = Process(target=f, args=(cell_lists ))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The error message is 'PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not the same object as cell.Cell'

Comment: It would help if you produced a self-contained simplified version of your code that demonstrates the error you are seeing.  That way others can run your code, and work to improve it.  Also, if you are getting a `PicklingError`, I'd suggest that you try `multiprocess`, which uses a better serializer.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I figure out the reason. Since I am using spyder to edit the script, everytime I run the script, there is a cell object be recorded in the memory, and if I don't create a new cell object to cover it up and directly pass the  old object to the function, python will complain about this. The solution is simple..., just restart all the script and create the new cell object.

Comment: You should post your own solution to your question, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike's suggestion. I figure out the problem. Since I am using spyder to edit the script. Everytime, to save time, I didn't create a new cell project instead of using the generated one. And this can mislead the python3 to another cell object. The simple way to avoid this problem is to restart the script or create a new cell object to avoid using the generated old cell object in the memory.